# Django transactions: how to run lots of sql query in the save mehod

Tags: python, django

I want to save more them 100 rows in my MySQL database, I have seen that experienced people are saying to use Django transactions. I'm using Django 3, wanted to know how to rite it and any resource that can help.
in my views.py I have used

from Django.db import transaction

## D is small in the code

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def single_user_images(request, *args, **kwargs):    

    if request.method == 'GET' and username:

    # I want to save the details here 
    # Receive the data


    else:
         #code
```

Please describe with an example if u have.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not per se transactions, you can o this with `bulk_create`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk_create

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you please provide any example.